# How do I display a message when clicking on an object in Visio using VBA?

Tags: vba, visio

I'm totally new on this so I want to start with something simple.

I have just an object in my Visio document and I want to display a `Hello World!` message whenever it's clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar to this using the SelectionAdded event on the Visio.Application class.  I check, if the selection.count is 1, then logically that shape has just been clicked, and if the shape type matches what you want, then display your message:

In the ThisDocument module (any object module, really):

```
Private WithEvents VsoApp As Visio.Application
Private Sub VsoApp_SelectionAdded(ByVal Selection As IVSelection)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

-Jon